# Why is Athena data scanned per query different for STRING and CHAR datatypes with Parquet source?

Tags: parquet, presto, amazon-athena

I have a bunch of files in Parquet format stored in S3 with a total size of 2.1GB. I am creating two tables in Athena which have the same schema except for the datatypes - in the first table, I am defining every column as a STRING whereas in the second table, I am using CHAR and VARCHAR.

When I run a query on the first table, Athena is scanning all the files and the data scanned is shown as 2.1G. When I run the same query on the second table, the data scanned is only 939 MB (which still seems a bit high since I expect Athena to only scan the requestId column and get the rows that match).

When I `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT *` using the same requestId, the data scanned in the first table is 261 MB whereas the data scanned in second table is still 939 MB. Why is this happening?

### Table 1

```
create external table table1 (
  `timestamp` string,
  level string,
  requestId string,
  class string,
  message string
)
stored as parquet
location 's3://...'
```

### Table 2

```
create external table table2 (
  `timestamp` char(24),
  level char(5),
  requestId char(36),
  class varchar(30),
  message varchar(255)
)
stored as parquet
location 's3://...'
```

### Queries

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."table1" where requestId='abcdef'
```

Time took: 4.47 seconds
Data scanned: 2.1G

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."table2" where requestId='abcdef'
```

Time took: 5.55 seconds
Data scanned: 939 MB

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "default"."table1" where requestId='abcdef'
```

Time took: 2.97 seconds
Data scanned: 261 MB

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "default"."table2" where requestId='abcdef'
```

Time took: 3.56 seconds
Data scanned: 939 MB

Edit: Swapped the stats for the count(*) queries

Comment: It's hard to discuss Athena internals, since it's closed source and it may be hard to guess answer otherwise. However, Athena is based on Presto .172. You can repeat the experiment with a recent Presto version. You can very easily run Presto 323 using Starburst AWS integration: https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/ (note: i am from Starburst).

Comment: BTW my guess is that's related to varchar/char coercion semantics that we fixed in Presto, so I'd hope Presto 323 would perform equally for chars and varchars now.

Comment: @rithvikp: can you confirm if the issue is still there with the new Athena engine?